# Net::SSH2 authentication without password

Tags: perl, authentication, cgi, catalyst, libssh2

I have a web interface and login mechanize in which authentication done by checking whether user can login on the server or no.

```
use Net::SSH2;

#Get  $un and $pw as POST data.

my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh2->connect('localhost') or die $!;

if($ssh2->auth_password($un, $pw) ){
    $c->session->{logged}  = 1;
}
```

I don't want to store any password for session.

And later in the flow I need to execute some command in the server by logged user.
So at this point I again need the password in order to make ssh2 authentication
(Execution can be later in the flow from other page).
My question is, once I make authentication first time, can I store anything (may be private key) for session or for user in order to not ask for password second time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do it that way.
Catalyst's Session can store user data, but you need to know that
Net::SSH2 is XS module, so, it Net::SSH2 object will be XS.
If you will try to store connected Net::SSH2 object you will get core dump.

Dump of the Net::SSH2 objet looks like:

```
$VAR1 = bless( do{\(my $o = 137381360)}, 'Net::SSH2' );
```

You're unable to serialize/deserialize XS object. You have to store password, or use different authentication mechanism, for example, key authentication.

Comment: I'm not gonna store $ssh2 object in session. What I need is somehow generate public/private keys  for user during first login. and then user key authentication during command execution.